# Record Access Calculation when OWD is public read/write and Grant Access Using Hierarchies selected

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, owd

This could be an academic question, but, what happens when the OWD of a custom object is Public Read/Write and the 'Grant Access Using Hierarchies' is selected?

Does it means that everytime we change a user from one role to another the calculation of the record access is triggered for this custom object?

Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the system is set to Public Read/Write, it typically does not evaluate Sharing Rules when a user changes roles (because it won't perform any unnecessary operations), but there's still some Group records that need to be updated (e.g. RolesAndSubordinates groups), to make sure that users lose or gain the Full Access permission for records they own, users below them, and for users above them.

These updates are virtually instantaneous, though, since very few records need to be updated behind the scenes, even in an org with hundreds of roles, the worst case scenario is only a few thousand records, and these records don't have triggers, validation rules, or other considerations to slow them down. It's usually recommended to perform mass role hierarchy updates while sharing is set to Public Read/Write to minimize the time the Share and Group tables need to be locked.